# Confusion regarding Fixed-Biased configuration of JFET

Tags: transistors, jfet, biasing

This is the picture of a fixed-biased JFET, taken from a book :-
[image]

This is written in the book, relating to the above pic :-
[image]

I am unable to understand why \$ V_{GS} \$ has a different polarity than \$ V_{GG} \$ in the first place. Shouldn't they be of the same polarity according to the connected terminals ?

Comment: A very poorly written book in my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Shouldn't they be of the same polarity according to the connected
>   terminals ?

No, the minus (-) terminal of the battery is indeed connected to the plus (+) side of \$V_{GS}\$, that is, the JFET gate (G).

All things considered, it's just an intrincate way of saying that \$V_{GS}\$ must be a negative voltage, i.e. the gate must have a negative bias voltage applied (when source is grounded).

**Note:** \$V_{GS}\$ means "Gate (G) to Source (S) Voltage". Voltage is a potential difference, and by definition that difference is \$V_G\$ ("positive" terminal) minus \$V_S\$ ("negative" terminal). However, such a difference can be negative (as it is in this case) because it's just a reference, a convention. The + and - signs doesn't tell you anything about which terminal is actually at a higher potential, just how the potential difference (voltage) has to be calculated.

Comment: Why is Gate the positive side of \$ V_{GS} \$ ?

Comment: Because \$V_{GS}\$ means "Gate (G) to Source (S) Voltage". Voltage is a potential difference, and by definition that difference goes from + to -. However, the difference can be negative (as it is in this case) because it's just a reference, a convention. The + and - signs doesn't tell you about which side is actually at a higher potential, but how the voltage is being referred.

Comment: I've edited the answer to add this explanation, as it seems to be what was actually confusing you.